How to get Single Map Instance from json response in flutter
I have Map Model as:
class Users {
  final int userID;
  final String name;
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final Address address;

  Users({this.userID, this.name, this.username, this.email, this.address});

  factory Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> usersjson)=> Users(
      userID: usersjson["id"],
      name: usersjson["name"],
      username: usersjson["username"],
      email: usersjson["email"],
      address: Address.fromJson(usersjson["address"])
  );
} 

And I got json response from http API.
For list of dala in Json we can convert to MAP Users as below
 List userList = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
    List<Users> myUserList = userList.map((data) => Users.fromJson(data)).toList();

But if i have single data in json response then how to get data in single instance of Users map?
like:
Users mySingleUser = Users.fromJson(response.body);


just check the length of the returned json List<Map<>>, check whether it contains more that one item or not, then assign it to a list or a single user.

Depending on the json you're handling you can do this

If the json is a single object and not a list. eg

{
  'id': '',
  'name': '',
  'username': '',
  'email': '',
  'address': '',
}

You can use this:
Users mySingleUser = Users.fromJson(response.body);

Or if you need to validate whether you're handling and object or a list you can do this
if (response.body is List) {
  return Users.fromJson(response.body[0]);
} else {
  return Users.fromJson(response.body);
}

And depending on your logic you can add validations to check if is not empty, if is an Map or something else depending on your requirements
